Blocking of IP address encountered during sign-up process
This is my first time to Stack Overflow. I tried to register, but failed repeatedly.
I had no way to ask for a solution here (since I had to register an account before I could post here).
The community support told me that my IP address is blocked by the account creation security systems.
In the end, my solution was to connect to the 5G network on my phone to register, and this time I successfully signed up.
How could it be that using a 5G network solve the problem?
If others use the same public Wi-Fi network as me and connect to a VPN or proxy, will it affect me?

How could it be that using a 5G network solve the problem? Different Network == Different Public IP. If the IP is blocked, then using a different IP solves the problem.

but the question is why the IP have been banned

You should use the contact page to address this.  An account is not required to do so.
Only staff can determine why your IP address is banned and consider lifting that ban.
